# Writing vector<double> to binary file and reading it again

Tags: c++, file, vector, binary

I'm trying to write a vector of doubles to a binary file.
After doing this I want to read it. This doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code:

```
ofstream bestand;
vector<double> v (32);
const char* pointer = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v[0]);
size_t bytes = v.size() * sizeof(v[0]);
bestand.open("test",ios::out | ios::binary);
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
   v[i] = i;
   cout << i;
   }
bestand.write(pointer, v.size());
bestand.close();
ifstream inlezen;
vector<double> v2 (32);
inlezen.open("test", ios::in | ios::binary);
char byte[8];
bytes = v2.size() * sizeof(v2[0]);
inlezen.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v2[0]), bytes);
for(int i =0; i < 32; i++){

 cout << endl << v2[i] << endl;
 }
```

This outputs "0 1 2 3 0 0 0......" so it seems it reads the first 4 numbers correctly.

Comment: The `write()` size argument is incorrect. It should be `v.size() * sizeof(double)`.

Comment: @K-ballo `skipws` doesn't apply to unformatted input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `.write()` takes the number of *bytes*, not the number of *items* to write:

```
bestand.write(pointer, v.size());
```

Since you've already computed the correct value, use it:

```
bestand.write(pointer, bytes );
```

Comment: This works thank you! Assume I have a for loop, writing a new vector <double> each iteration to the same file. What do I have to change to the read? Also but this in a for loop?

Comment: Ok nvm I've figured it out :). Thanks